# specify the interface for automated backups

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, backup, duplicity

I am running automated backups with duplicity, but I need a way to execute it from a specific network interface.
Right now it has 2 interfaces:
eno1-> local network ( say IP is: 1.1.1.1)
eno2-> public (say ip is: 2.2.2.2)

I need a way to have duplicity use eno2, like for example when you use ping to ping from specific interface :

```
ping -I eno2 google.com
```

My script.sh:

```
...
PASSPHRASE="Password" duplicity --encrypt-key 000000000000000000000 --scp-command "scp -oBindAddress=2.2.2.2" /mnt/ntfs/share/ https://Admin:Password@example/remote.php/webdav/share/
...
```

however, the **scp-command "scp -oBindAddress=2.2.2.2"** doesn't work and backups are still performed through 1.1.1.1 bottlenecking the entire network.

Can anyone please help me select the interface?
Thanks

Comment: [MAN page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/duplicity): `--scp-command command  Deprecated and ignored. The sftp/scp backend does no longer use an external scp client program. ` hardly surprising that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

normaly the traffic should be "bound" to a interface by the systems routing table. You can inspect it with the `route -n` command.

You can send the traffic to a IP or Network by a specific interface by adding a new entry to that routing table:

`route add -host <destination ip address> metric 1024 dev eno1`

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try this, but can I switch it for everything but lan? I want interface 1 (eno1) to be used just for lan), and anything that goes out to internet to use interface 2 (eno2). Thanks

Comment: you can create a route for your internal network pointing to device eno1 and a "default" route to your internet gateway for eno2. If you can access your system this should already work!